# mvc to net core 2 migrate authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-2.0

Hi I have a mvc web site and I have to migrate it to net core 2. The old site has cookie and facebook authentication configure this way:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{    
    LoginPath = "LoginPath",
    CookieName = "CookieName",  
    CookieDomain = "CookieDomain",
    CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
        {
            //Some logic and redirection
        }
    }
});

app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
{
    CallbackPath = "CallbackPath",,
    AppId = "AppId",
    AppSecret = "AppSecret",
    Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnApplyRedirect = (context) =>
        {
           //Some logic and redirection
        },
        OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
        {
            //Some logic and add claim
        }
    }
});
```

Now I have:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(
                    options =>
                        {
                            options.LoginPath = "LoginPath";
                            options.CookieName = "CookieName";
                            options.CookieDomain = "CookieDomain";
                        })
                .AddFacebook(options =>
                    {
                        CallbackPath = "CallbackPath";
                        AppId = "AppId";
                        AppSecret = "AppSecret";
                    });
```

But I cannot find the "Provider" to put the OnApplyRedirect and OnAuthenticated legacy logic that I have. Where I should place this logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = Configuration.GetSection("Facebook:ApplicationId").Value;
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration.GetSection("Facebook:Password").Value;
    options.Events = new OAuthEvents
    {
        OnCreatingTicket = context =>
        {
            // do something with context
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    };
});
```